# partitioning 500GB HDD

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning

I am building my new PC. Can any one guide me in partitioning 500GB HDD. I like to install windows 7 on it. How many primary partitions I can create and best space allocation approach and best partitioning tools.

Comment: Unless you have a reason to divide the drive into multiple partitions, and know what that reason is, don't bother.

Answer (score 3):

For regular usage, you can just use one primary partition and you'll probably be fine.

If you want to get fancy, you can have a Windows partition and then a data partition. This separates your system files from your data. If you choose to do this, the amount of space you allocate to each really depends upon your usage. I would allocate 150-200 GB for programs and 300-350 GB for data.

Comment: data partitions means extended partition? any tools I can use for partitioning?

Comment: Windows Setup allows you partition the disk before installing Windows.  You don't really need any extra tools.

Comment: @HarryJohnston But partitioning while installing windows creating all primary partitions only. There won't be any issue is we have all primary partitions only?

Comment: The only reason to use extended partitions is if you want more than four partitions in total.  In this case you'll only have three: the boot ("system") partition, the Windows partition and the data partition.